# Error DuplicateKeyException when setting the id manually on Insert

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a table which generates its primary key from a sequence:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[seq_PK_testTable] AS [int] START WITH 0 INCREMENT BY 1;
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testTable](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_testTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY];
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[testTable] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_testTable_id] DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [seq_PK_testTable]) FOR [id];
```

In order to be able to work with this key generation mechanism, I've chosen to use the `Insert` partial method of the data context, as proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54464277/853468).

For the first insert it works like a charm: the insert is performed and the ID is updated in the object, but as soon as I insert a second object I get a `System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException: 'Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use.'`.

The [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```cs
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace test
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var db = new DataClasses1DataContext(@"Data Source=");
            var testTableRecord1 = new testTable();
            var testTableRecord2 = new testTable();
            db.GetTable<testTable>().InsertOnSubmit(testTableRecord1);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            db.GetTable<testTable>().InsertOnSubmit(testTableRecord2);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }

    [Database(Name = "TestDB")]
    public class DataClasses1DataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
    {
        public DataClasses1DataContext(string fileOrServerOrConnection) : base(fileOrServerOrConnection) { }

        void InserttestTable(testTable instance)
        {
            using(var cmd = Connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[seq_PK_testTable] as NextId";
                cmd.Transaction = Transaction;
                instance.id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                ExecuteDynamicInsert(instance);
            }
        }
    }

    [Table(Name = "dbo.testTable")]
    public class testTable
    {
        [Column(DbType = "Int NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
        public int id;
    }
}
```

I assume it internally still expects the `id` to be `0`. How can I force LINQ to reflect the real id?

PS: because the question has been flagged as a duplicate of [LINQ to SQL insert primary key index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641528/linq-to-sql-insert-primary-key-index): `IsPrimaryKey = true` and `IsDbGenerated = true` doesn't work because they cause LINQ to SQL to generate code that queries for an `IDENTITY` ID, i.e. `SELECT CONVERT(Int,SCOPE_IDENTITY())` and that returns `NULL` if the ID has been created with the default value of a `SEQUENCE`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187845/discussion-on-question-by-beat-error-duplicatekeyexception-when-setting-the-id-m).

Comment: @YvetteColomb and now this question will never be answered, while the same comments will be posted by others

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos everyone here has the rep to chat. There comes a point when 30 + comments are too many

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this by instantiating a new instance of the DataContext for each insert operation.

```
var db = new DataClasses1DataContext(@"Data Source=");   
var testTableRecord1 = new testTable();
db.GetTable<testTable>().InsertOnSubmit(testTableRecord1);
db.SubmitChanges();

db = new DataClasses1DataContext(@"Data Source=");    
var testTableRecord2 = new testTable();
db.GetTable<testTable>().InsertOnSubmit(testTableRecord2);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

If you want to understand what is happening, try putting a breakpoint inside the parital InsertTestTable method. You'll see that it isn't getting called after the second call to SubmitChanges(). Each instance of the data context maintains a cache containing every entity that is inserted, updated, or retrieved. The cache behaves like a dictionary using the primary key of the entity as the dictionary key. For some reason, LINQ is only running the custom insert logic once per cached entity. IMO this is a bug in LINQ, and I cannot find any documentation that justifies this behavior.

To understand what I mean, try setting the id of each entity to a separate value, and you'll see that the custom insert behavior actually works correctly:

```
var db = new DataClasses1DataContext(@"Data Source=");   
var testTableRecord1 = new testTable(){ id = -1 };
var testTableRecord2 = new testTable(){ id = -2 };
db.GetTable<testTable>().InsertOnSubmit(testTableRecord1);
db.SubmitChanges();
db.GetTable<testTable>().InsertOnSubmit(testTableRecord2);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

My advice is to create a new instance of the data context before each call to SubmitChanges(), OR batch your inserts to a single SubmitChanges (this is best, if possible). When using LINQ, the data context should generally be treated as a short-lived, disposable object.